# Remove Pod reference from old commit that was committed by mistake

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I  need to remove pod reference from old commit in a particular branch.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! No need to ask "please" -- We're here to help! 

Please give us more details.. What do you mean by "pod reference"? A reference in your `Podfile`?

Comment: file reference of some pods in project.pbx file that was added unintentionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `Pods` folder and the `Podfile.lock` file, and then run `pod setup && pod install`